# How to build firefox as installer

Tags: firefox

Now I'm trying to build firefox according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Simple_Firefox_build
So I can get firefox from mozilla-release\obj-i686-pc-mingw32\dist\bin folder.
I want to get setup.exe from this result.
How can I build firefox as installer type.

Answer (score 2):

`./mach build installer` is both the official way to build a Firefox installer, and the way that worked for me.

**Note:** it will put the installer in `mozilla-release\obj-i686-pc-mingw32\dist\install\sea\firefox-36.0a1.en-US.win32.installer.exe` (where “36.0a1” is replaced whatever version you're compiling.

**Note 2:** You may need to add the line `mk_add_options WIN32_REDIST_DIR="$VCINSTALLDIR\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC80.CRT"` (or similar) to your .mozconfig to build a version that installs on non-developer’s computers.  This part didn’t actually work for me.  :(